Add a value for sprint in an existing JIRA ticket using invoke-restmethod
I would like to add a sprint value (or name or string or id) in an existing JIRA ticket via Powershell and more specifically invoke-restmethod (not with curl).
Could somebody mention me an existing link or give me a example ?

Based on available online documentation, it would seem you need to send a POST request to /rest/agile/1.0/sprint/{sprintId}/issue:
$jiraHostName = "https://<jira host name goes here>"
$targetSprintId = 123                     # replace with actual sprint identifier
$oauthBearerToken = "<token goes here>"   # see https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/jira-oauth-2-0-provider-api-1115659070.html
$issuesToUpdate = @(                      # replace with actual issue identifiers
  'PROJ-123',
  'PROJ-456'
)

$irmArgs = @{
  Uri = "${jiraHostName}/rest/agile/1.0/sprint/${targetSprintId}/issue"
  Headers = @{
    'Authorization' = "Bearer $oauthBearerToken"
    'X-Atlassian-Token' = 'nocheck'
  }
  Method = Post
  Body = @{
    'issues' = $issuesToUpdate
  }
  ContentType = 'application/json'
}

Invoke-RestMethod @irmArgs


Thanks Mathias. I'm going to test.

Hello Mathias. I have tried your script but I got an issue : Invoke-RestMethod : 404null for uri: http://jira:8010/jira/rest/api/2/rest/agile/1.0/issue/sprint/24124/issue
At D:\Scripts\eventCreation\JIRA_AddSprint.ps1:26 char:3

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -ContentType 'application/json' -Uri  ...





@JTR The error text clearly shows you're running something other than the code provided in my answer. Make sure the method used is Post, not Put, and perhaps try removing the /jira part from the hostname if it still returns 404 (eg. $jiraHostName = "https://jira:8010")
